# Textbox Valid using Vue Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Please Help me .. Sir ...
I want to check if one text input is null, which causes an error indicated by a red border. But when i fill one input the error border appears on both of text inputs.

```
<el-form-item label="Deadline Building" :error="errorBag.leased_land_year || errorBag.leased_land_month">

              <el-input name="leased_land_year" v-model="form.leased_land_year" placeholder="2007" style="width: 180px;">
                   <template slot="append">Y</template></el-input>

              <el-input name="leased_land_month" v-model="form.leased_land_month" placeholder="2" style="width: 150px;" >
                    <template slot="append">M</template></el-input>

</el-form-item>
```